# Number with a set of digits

Tags: python, math, numbers

Lets say you are given a set of n consecutive digits  , Ex {0,1,2,3}.
You are required to form a number using the digits which abides by the following rule:

1.The number should cover all relations (ex 12 and 21) between any 2 digits from the set of numbers

For the given set, this number would be 0123130203210 or 0123021310320.

I was able to get this number manually by trial and error.
Is there a deterministic way of achieving this number for any n consecutive digits?

The number will have all the 2 digit permutations only once.

```
0 -> [1,2,3] will yield 01 , 02 , 03
1 -> [0,2,3] will yield 10 , 12 , 13
2 -> [0,1,3] will yield 20 , 21 , 23
3 -> [0,1,2] will yield 30 , 31 , 32
```

when a list is given it should combine that particularly given number with list.

We have to generate a number which will cover all the above relations.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Hi @Spaz, welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and add your attempt to the problem to the problem. Please note, SO is not a homework assistance portal.

Comment: Why is there an extra `0` at the end of both example results?

Comment: Do you mean "all permutations"? Neither of your results has all permutations of the digits.

Comment: Can you please let me know if it clear now or more details are required to re-open this ticket?